# Impersonate using json credentials file

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a service account setting up with domain wide delegation to Gsuite domain.
I'd like to impersonate one of the users to be the organizer of a created event.

My code is:

```
                List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
                scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
                scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_EVENTS);


                InputStream credentialsJSON = Service5.class.getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream("credentials.json");

                GoogleCredential gcFromJson = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsJSON, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY).createScoped(scopes);

                GoogleCredential cred =  new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(gcFromJson.getTransport())
                        .setJsonFactory(gcFromJson.getJsonFactory())
                        .setServiceAccountId(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountId())
                        .setServiceAccountUser("edt@company.tn")
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountScopes())
                        .build();
                Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, cred).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();


                Event event = new Event().setSummary("Test");

                DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2020-04-27T09:00:00.000Z");
                EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                                      .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                                      .setTimeZone("Africa/Tunis");
                event.setStart(start);

                DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2020-04-27T10:30:00.000Z");
                EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                                    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                                    .setTimeZone("Africa/Tunis");
                event.setEnd(end);

                List<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
                EventAttendee ens = new EventAttendee().setEmail("user@company.tn");
                attendees.add(ens);
                event.setAttendees(attendees);

                String calendarId = "primary";
                event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

But I got that exception:

[image]

**EDIT - 1**
I downloaded the json file resulted from `CREATE KEY`

Got that exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401
>   Unauthorized  at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:394)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:493)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>     at tn.esprit.spring.google.calendar.Service5.main(Service5.java:183)

Could you please tell me what I missed?.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does the content of your `credentials.json` file look like and how did you obtain it?

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply. It looks like `{"installed":{"client_id":"myClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"quickstart-1586641968471","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"myClientsecret","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}` . I obtained it from enabling Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To use a service account, you need to create dedicated service accounts credentials

- Go to the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard)
- Choose a project
- Go on `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials`
- Choose `+ CREATE CREDENTIALS` -> `Service Account`
- Choose a `Service account name` and click on `Create`
- If desired, you can select a role (optional)
- Click on `Create key` and select `JSON` (p12 is also possible, but you will need to build `GoogleCredential` differently
- The **correct** `json` file will be downloaded to your computer

It will look as following:

```
{
"type": "service_account",
...
```

The json file you were using was not the right one for service accounts, it did not have the field `type` specified - thus the error `'type' field not specified`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for your help, I have an account service , and as presented on my question (EDIT-1), by clicking on `CREATE KEY` buttom, I got the json file with `"type": "service_account"`, but now I got another exception `Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized`. Could you please take a look on my question with Edition part. am I missing something ?. big thanks Sir.

Comment: Did you give your service account the necessary scopes in the admin console? See [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)

Comment: On the admin console -> security, with the `Client Name` I have those scopes `View and manage the provisioning of groups on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar
View and manage the provisioning of users on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`

Comment: Did you assign to the new service account you just created?

Comment: I have already a service account setting up with domain wide delegation to Gsuite domain created a week ago. So, as described by capture 2 (Edit - 1), I just download the json file after clicking on `CREATE KEY` button. Sir, It didn't work with that service account, Should  I create a new one?.

Comment: You should go on `Security > API controls` or `Security > Advanced Settings > Manage API client access` and give the necessary scopes to the same service account for which you downloaded the credentials. You can find the respective client name in GCP.

Comment: that is it Sir what I did, and the scopes are `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`, am I forgot a required scope ? Big thanks Sir.

Comment: You are `inserting` events, so a `readonly` scope is not enough

Comment: That is it. Thanks a lot Sir @ziganotschka for your help. Really, you're so kind.